# Which is a better option for multitasking in arduino - millis( ) or Scheduler Library?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, multitasking

I have an application wherein I want to flash( trigger for a sec) a solenoid every 10 seconds and at the same time receive a serial input to rotate a servo motor.

The `delay()` creates conflicts so I have gone through the `millis()` function which is easy to understand.But in the arduino website they have something called the Scheduler library which looks pretty damn easy( haven't tried it though).

So which is better and efficient option to consider, is it `millis()` or Scheduler?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scheduler library uses `millis()` as well to calculate the delay between tasks.

To link a function to the sheduler, it needs to have a `void f(void)` prototype.

So to be able to add a function that returns something or has parameters, you need to wrap it in another function of `void f(void)` prototype.

IMHO, a sheduler library is usefull to organize your code when you have multiple tasks (This library has a maximum of 10 tasks, but you can change it).

In your case, you only have two tasks. It may be better to just use your own little sheduler using `millis()`.

Comment: @Ouss4Thank you for the info.I did try with millis() and it worked fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with millis(), then 
[Simple Multi-tasking in Arduino](https://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Multi-tasking-in-Arduino-on-Any-Board/) 
will be of help.  It covers:- adding a loopTimer to see how slow your loop/tasks are running, removing delays from your code and third party libraries, reading serial input without blocking and sending serial prints without blocking and giving important tasks more time.

Finally it transfers the code unchanged to the ESP32 to add remote control.

The basic code is

```
void loop() {
 callTask_1(); // do something
 callTask_2(); // do something else
 callTask_1(); // check the first task again as it needs to be more responsive than the others.
 callTask_3(); // do something else
}
```

The trick is that each callTask..() method must return quickly so that the other tasks in the loop get called promptly and often. The rest of the instructable covers how to keep your tasks running quickly and not holding everything up, using a temperature controlled, stepper motor driven damper with a user interface as a concrete example.